# Is there a way to figure out the rate at which records are added in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get time range of when our application is being stressed. I have a table that has a record written to it for each process with a time stamps. I want the time ranges where there are at least 3 records per minute.

Heres a version of the table if it helps

```
SELECT TOP (1000) ItemId
      ,[TimeStamp]
FROM[ExportQueue]
```

TimeStamp is in DateTime

Comment: Group by minute and filter by `having count(*) >= 3` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to count groups of dates/times with the same date to the nearest minute, such as

```
select top (1000) ItemId 
from ExportQueue
group by 
  ItemId, 
  DateTimeFromParts(
    Year([Timestamp]),
    Month([Timestamp]),
    Day([Timestamp]),
    DatePart(hour,[Timestamp]),
    DatePart(minute,[Timestamp]),
    0,0)
having Count(*)>=3;
```